# How to get Adview below Viewpager in CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout

At the moment the `AdView` is appearing inside the `ViewPager` so its blocking the content in the app. How can I get the `AdView` to appear below the `ViewPager` and not inside.

I have tried to put the `AdView` in a `RelativeLayout` below the `ViewPager` but then the `AdView` doesn't show at all.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.candyx.testapp.Activity">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/main_button_background">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorTabIndicator"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
        android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You can add `ViewPager` and `AdView` inside `RelativeLayout` and specify `android:layout_above="@+id/adView"` property to `ViewPager` so that `adView` doesn't block the `ViewPager` contents.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.candyx.testapp.Activity">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adView">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/main_button_background">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorTabIndicator"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
        android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The problem with this is that now it pushes the content up and under the toolbar about the banner size so I think its the new coordinator layout that doesn't want to play along. I don't really want it nested inside the viewpager but I guess only solution so far is to put banner size bottom padding on my recyclerview

Comment: Nope it's still inside the viewpager at the bottom but it's ok ill just use the bottom padding on the recyclerview so when you scroll to the bottom there is a blank space for the ad

Comment: Did u add this line `android:layout_above="@+id/adView"`  to `CoordinatorLayout`? There is no way it is inside `ViewPager` . I have tested in a sample app :)

Comment: Oops I didn't see that. Yes now it works perfect thanks alot

Comment: consider also adding `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` to center your add banner.

Comment: It works but I am getting a white overlay in the status bar like shown in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32428700/1820644

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, you deserve a nobel price.

Comment: @40-Love Share the full layout

Comment: I'm finding that the main activity content is pushed up by the height of the adview, so that the top of the activity is under the toolbar.  Any hints?

Comment: @drmrbrewer Can you share your layout structure?

Comment: @AbhishekV I'm finding it difficult to know how to do this in a comment, so I'll summarise it.  I have `RelativeLayout` at top level, and within that: `Toolbar`, `CoordinatorLayout` and `AdView`.  Within the `CoordinatorLayout` I have a `NestedScrollView` and within that a `LinearLayout` with my main content for the activity.  I have used your `android:layout_above` trick in the `CoordinatorLayout` to put it above the `AdView`, but this pushes it under the `Toolbar`.  I can't help noticing that your `Toolbar` is within the `CoordinatorLayout` (mine is outside).

Comment: Maybe I need an `android:layout_above` in the `Toolbar` to explicitly put it above the `CoordinatorLayout`?  I also wonder why we have to use a `RelativeLayout` and be explicit about ordering like this... why can't we just lay out elements in the order we want, in a `LinearLayout`?

Comment: Solution was to add `android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"` to `CoordinatorLayout`

Answer (score 8):

Put ViewPager and Adview inside a another LinearLayout as below:

```
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
     <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
            android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I edited my answer. Forgot to mention about LinearLayout earlier.

Comment: please provide some xml layout for view pager circular page indicator and below recycler view with floating action button sample

Comment: This is the best answer. Worked for me!

Comment: Excellent answer!

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me :
just put inside the ViewPager the app:layout_behavior :

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried the answer by @AvishekV but that didn't solve my problem. But I took **THE IDEA of putting CoordinatorLayout and Adview inside a parent layout** which in my case was **ConstraintLayout**. Below is the structure

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
       android:id="@+id/content"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/adView"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
           //CollapsingToolbarLayout
           //ConstraintLayout, if you need to put anything inside collpasingtoolbar
           //Toolbar
           //TabLayout
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="your adunit id"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

as i test on real device thats work for me :**Fix Height Declear On Bottom Child**
`

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/htab_maincontent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/PanelView"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!--android:fitsSystemWindows="false">-->

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/htab_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/htab_collapse_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="256dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/htab_header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/title_panel_main"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/htab_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="104dp"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:titleMarginTop="13dp" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/htab_tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/tab_viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/PanelView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="7dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:visibility="visible">



    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
         />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>`
```

Hope Help You

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/lyt_navigation">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:titleTextAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceHeadline6" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
    android:id="@+id/lyt_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:backgroundTint="?attr/colorBottomNav"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
        app:elevation="@dimen/dp_8"
        android:layoutDirection="ltr"
        app:itemTextAppearanceActive="@style/BottomNavigationView.Active"
        app:itemTextAppearanceInactive="@style/BottomNavigationView"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/color_bottom_tab_text"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
         android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight"
         app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:id="@+id/view_banner_ad"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.solodroid.ads.sdk.ui.BannerAdView
            android:id="@+id/bannerAdView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers).  While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are.  Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.