# Status bar turns white and does not show content behind it

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-appcompat, androiddesignsupport, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am trying out AppCompat on Marshmallow. And I want to have a transparent status bar however it turns white. I've tried a couple solutions but they didn't work for me ([Transparent status bar not working with windowTranslucentNavigation="false"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28289477/transparent-status-bar-not-working-with-windowtranslucentnavigation-false), [Lollipop : draw behind statusBar with its color set to transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27856603/lollipop-draw-behind-statusbar-with-its-color-set-to-transparent)). Here's related code.

My styles.xml

```
<style name="Bacon" parent="Theme.Bacon"/>

<style name="Theme.Bacon" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/theme_primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/theme_primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/theme_accent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background_material_light</item>  
</style>

<style name="Theme.Bacon.Detail" parent="Bacon"/>
```

v21

```
<style name="Bacon" parent="Theme.Bacon">
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.Bacon.Detail" parent="Bacon">
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Activity

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Fragment

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="192dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="32dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:statusBarScrim="@color/black_trans80">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/photo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/photo"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/anim_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Are you able to solve this issue? I am having the same issue. In one of my activity having white status bar

Comment: @kirtan403 I fixed my issue by changing my Activity layout from FrameLayout to RelativeLayout. Please see my answer.

Comment: Mine is Relative only still getting the white statusbar. I have posted question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33890066/1820644

Comment: After struggling for a day I found the solution which worked for me. Here is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33892569/1820644

Comment: I changed android:windowTranslucentStatus status to false and its working

Comment: I have faced the same issue and solved it by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56989333/8874958)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed my issue by changing my Activity layout from FrameLayout to RelativeLayout. Thanks everybody who tried to help!

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
      android:id="@+id/pager"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="@color/theme_primary_dark"
      android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Try [hierarchy-viewer](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/hierarchy-viewer.html) or [ViewInspector](https://github.com/xfumihiro/ViewInspector). These tools might help you.

Answer (score 171):

I found the answer in this link:[Status Bar Color not changing with Relative Layout as root element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37454733/status-bar-color-not-changing-with-relative-layout-as-root-element)

So it turns out we need remove the

```
      <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

in styles.xml(v21). And it works just fine for me.

Comment: Yes, this is the solution. Because android:fitsSystemWindows will cause problems when making the tab bar scrollable. Found the same answer but you posted it earlier. Also mention that this is default overwritten I think.

Comment: This should be marked as the accepted solution. This issue was creeping up all over my app, this solution fixed it everywhere just by commenting out that single line. Saved me such a headache!

Comment: I'm using CoordinatorLayout, so the other answer to us CoordinatorLayout as the root doesn't work for me (using fitsSystemWindows=true as suggested didn't work either). This answer works for me.

Comment: What if I require my status bar color to be transparent though?

Comment: @nullmn then you need change your Activity background to something else.

Answer (score 99):

(A little late to the party but it might help someone)

I had the exact same problem. Somehow, some activities were normal while new ones I created were showing white status bar instead of `colorPrimaryDark` value.

After trying several tips, I noticed that the normal-working activities where all using `CoordinatorLayout` as the root of the layout, while for the others I had replaced it by regular layouts because I didn't need the features (animation, etc) provided by `CoordinatorLayout`.

So the solution is to make `CoordinatorLayout` the root layout, and then inside of it add your former layout root. Here is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <!-- your activity content here-->


  </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

PLEASE NOTE that without `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` this solution doesn't work for me.

Tested on Lollipop and Marshmallow

Comment: The solution worked for me too. But.. why does it happen? Proper StatusBar color is displayed when root is DrawerLayout or CoordinatorLayout

Comment: This only worked for me when adding `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to the `CoordinatorLayout` in Android 8.

Comment: @Franco I think this is the most relevant part of the solution. I say this because I had `CoordinatorLayout` when I experienced the same problem and the specific property that fixed this for me was `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`

Comment: The `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` did not work for me. What solved my problem is to use a theme that's not `AppTheme.NoActionBar` on the activity with a `CoordinatorLayout`. I don't know why that fixed it.

Comment: `CoordinatorLayout` or `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` neither is working for me.

Answer (score 23):

You have to add this property on your style to see the content

```
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar" tools:ignore="NewApi">true</item>
```

Comment: This worked for me. This should be accepted answer.

Answer (score 19):

```
 <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    </style
```

> Just Replace this , statusBarColor should be your expected color and not TRANSPARENT

Answer (score 12):

Add this in your style.xml

```
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

and this in your onCreate();

```
 getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
       View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't work. The status bar looks the same.

Comment: please help for this issue... same problem here.... none of the solutions till now works

Comment: @SaeedJassani  I found a solution which worked for me. If you have same problem have a look at my question and answer : stackoverflow.com/a/33892569/1820644

Answer (score 10):

Just put this item in your v21\styles.xml :

true

It should look like this :

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: It worked for me using `false` values in the last 2 items. Weird, but thanks.

Comment: It does work for only with the two last lines but the content is going behind the status bar, padding/margin or fitsSystemWindows does not help. Tested on OP 5 running nougat

Answer (score 9):

After unsuccessfully trying all of the above I found that explicitly setting the theme fixed the issue.

```
setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
```

That has to go before the super.OnCreate() in your activity.

Comment: I can confirm this fixes the errant activity on Marshmallow

Comment: love you man , worked like a charm, though i still have no idea why :@

Comment: before the super.OnCreate() is the key

Answer (score 9):

I faced the same issue. What i did was, in the "v21/styles.xml" file a changed the value true:

```
 <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
```

to:

```
 <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>
```

Answer (score 7):

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

You'll see that line of code in values/styles/styles.xml(v21) . Remove it and that solves the issue

[Link to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39681554/5003295)

Answer (score 5):

Just remove following tag from style v21 
 @android:color/transparent

This works for me.

Comment: @android:color/transparent is not a "tag". It may be the value of a style attribute, but it is not a "tag". What if the OP has this value defined more than once? Which one should he remove? Your answer is far too generic.

Comment: yeah, it was the case for me too.. thank you, Shendre! :) and for your comment, @protectedmember - the OS has no gender.

Answer (score 5):

I have found solution for this -

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
</style>
```

add this into your style and it will work for api 21 or above.

Answer (score 3):

Better approach

Check your style.xml file where your NoActionBar theme is there.
Make sure its has parent as Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar and also customize it by adding your color scheme. Finally set your themes in manifest as required.

Below is sample of my styles.xml file (ActionBar + NoActionBar).

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<!-- No ActionBar application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

For styles v23

```
 <style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

For styles v21

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

If your v21/styles.xml contain

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Then,
**Remove** or **comment** below line or change colour of status bar,

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

Its working fine. Hope this is helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For me it worked by doing the following :

1. Set the theme  `.NoActionBar`
2. Wrap the Toolbar in `android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout`
3. Make `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout` as the parent layout.

Essentially it is the third step that draws the status bar in the `colorPrimaryDark` otherwise it is not drawn if you using `NoActionBar` theme. 
2nd step will give your toolbar that *overlay*.

Answer (score 2):

[[image: Output]]

Expand res -> values -> styles directory from project panel.

Open styles.xml (v21)

**USE ANY ONE FROM BELOW WAYS**

1. Change **true** to **false** in `android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds` property.
2. Change **@android:color/transparent** to **@color/colorPrimaryDark** in `android:statusBarColor` property.
3. Remove the `android:statusBarColor` propert line.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's late but i hope it helps someone. 
* Make a fake view with transparent background that fits the layout, and make a coordinatorlayout as your root layout element.

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/something" />

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

   .... YOUR LAYOUT
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

you want this right?

try this. in [value] - [style.xml]

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
</style>
```

you know, don't match apptheme - parent

good luck

Answer (score 1):

Inside `onCreate` add the following:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
       getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.WHITE);
```

and below

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/white</item>
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
```

When you do this, the time etc. appears on the white status bar.
Or you can also give it a transparent color.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this is caused by your `android:windowBackground`. Is `@color/background_material_light` a reference to white?

Comment: Nope. It's definitely not white but thanks anyway! (You can see the white icons on it.)

Comment: I misread your question. Try replacing `<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>` with `<item name="android:statusBarColor">@null</item>`.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand you correctly, do you want the image to be shown behind the status bar?

Answer (score 0):

Check this 
Toolbar turns white - AppBar isn't drawn after being scrolled off screen

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=178037#c19

I'm using libraries 23.0.0. and the bug still occurs.

Workaround for this is adding View that takes nearly no space and can be invisible. See the structure below.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height=".3dp"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

This Questions on Stackoverflow.com refer to this bug too: 
[CoordinatorLayout Toolbar invisible on enter until full height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30895579/coordinatorlayout-toolbar-invisible-on-enter-until-full-height)
[AppBarLayout - Layout sometimes invisible once it enters view (even if it's not entered)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31084658/appbarlayout-layout-sometimes-invisible-once-it-enters-view-even-if-its-not)

Comment: it's not the same bug. in my case, it's white right after activity shows not after being scrolled off screen. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **RelativeLayout / CoordinatorLayout** this is the solution that worked for me:

You have to use

- CoordinatorLayout
- AppBarLayout

**Rember to use CoordinatorLayout instead of RelativeLayout** (the performance is better and perfectly works with AppBarLayout)

This is how your fragment should starts

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/background_light"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/main.appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >
    ...
```

Good coding!

Answer (score 0):

```
 <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

add the 'windowTranslucentStatus' item in styles

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your style.xml

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

Note : Status bar coloring is not supported below API level 21.

Answer (score -1):

```
    Window window = this.getWindow();
    window.setStatusBarColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
```

Add this 2 line in java file below

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you please elaborate how your piece of code works and how it helps solving OPs Question? Please refer to [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to improve your answer