# Status Bar Color not changing with Relative Layout as root element

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

I am just starting to learn android, I am learning to add AppBar. But if I use Relative Layout as the root then Status Bar don't use the color "colorPrimaryDark" defined in the theme. But changing the layout to **CoordinatorLayout** make it works.

Can someone explain the difference? is it a requirement to use the CoordinatorLayout Layout?

Activity Extends AppCompatActivity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.ankit.designdemo.MainActivity">


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.ankit.designdemo.MainActivity">


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image]

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.custom_activity);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


}
```

Comment: Can you show styles where you defined `colorPrimaryDark`?

Comment: @hrskrs Added to the question..

Comment: Are you sure your styles page is on `values-v21`?

Comment: Firstly you don't need the `CoordinatorLayout` in order to use `Toolbar`. The status bar should be colored with your `colorPrimaryDark` out of the box just because you inherit from `AppCompatActivity`, so I couldn't reproduce your problem is there any manipulation you are doing in your code?

Comment: @Alex.F, I just created new android project with Scrolling Activity, hadn't touched any code except main_activity.xml file.. It automatically got created with coordinate layout and was working fine.. As I was referring to some tutorial so used relative layout..  that's it.. Nothing else changed.

Comment: @ironman I don't see any answer mate..

Comment: @hrskrs I am not sure what you mean but I do see 2 style files.. one under values and 1 values-21..  what I posted in question is values/style.xml  ,, as I understand that 21 variation should run only on api level 21.. but emulator I am testing is on 23..

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In `v21/styles.xml` you probably have this line of code:

```
  <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

And as you are running on `API 23`, the declared styles are overrided from the ones in `v21/styles.xml`.

As a solution:

**Just remove that line and it will work fine**

Comment: spot on, My problem is solved and as I am learning,  can you please add clarification about override.. I was under impression that v21/styles.xml will come to use only on API 23.. Also why things were working with CoordinatorLayout that will a good addition as well

Comment: @Ankit About styles you can read [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) on how they work based on platform. About `CoordinatorLayout`: it works because of `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`, if you remove it it will show you same behaviour.

Comment: I see now.. so v21/styles.xml is going to run when API 21 or above.. Thanks for helping..

Comment: @Ankit yeap, declared styles will be taken from `v21/styles.xml`, non-declared ones but declared on `styles.xml`, it will be taken from `styles.xml`

Answer (score 2):

The styling of the statusbar is done by the

```
android:fitsSystemWindows
```

tag. This is currently not supported for RelativeLayout. Either you try another layout like FrameLayout which could work but for know i would suggest to stick to the CoordinatorLayout.

Maybe you get some more details here: 
https://medium.com/google-developers/why-would-i-want-to-fitssystemwindows-4e26d9ce1eec

Answer (score 0):

just add this

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
```