# Viewpager becomes too high

Tags: android, android-studio, layout, tabs, android-viewpager

I'm setting up a tabbed Android app. For this I started with the activity created by Android Studio of type *Tabbed Activity* with the style set to *Action Bar Tabs (with ViewPager)*.

The resulting main activity has a `CoordinatorLayout`, containing the `AppBarLayout` and `ViewPager` (the floating button is not interesting for this case).

Since the `ViewPager` has a height of `match_parent`, I wondered if it would extend beyond the bottom of the screen. To test it, I added a `TextView` to the fragment that is used inside the `ViewPager` and aligned it to the bottom.

When running the app I could not see the extra `TextView`. After I changed the height of the `ViewPager` to 400dp, the `TextView` became visible.

So my assumption is that the `ViewPager` gets the same height as the parent, but the `AppBar` takes up space at the top, so the `ViewPager` is shifted down. Now how should the height of the `ViewPager` be set up properly, so that it takes up all the remaining space under the `AppBar`? The only possible values for the height are `match_parent`, `wrap_content` and a fixed value.

I hope there's an "xml only" solution.

For completeness, here's the layout of the main activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                             android:id="@+id/main_content"
                                             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                             android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                             android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                                             tools:context="nl.ravelin.so_tabs.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and the main fragment

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            tools:context="nl.ravelin.so_tabs.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/section_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="How low can you go."/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: screen shot please

Comment: See since its a `coordinatorLayout` with `Scroll` behaviour for `AppBarLayout`, `viewpager` will take space which equal to `screen_height -  toolbar_height`, So that when `viewpager` scroll up the toolbar will go out of the screen and `viewpager` will become fully visible. Now if you don't want this behaviour than instead of `coordinatorLayout` you can use `LinearLayout` but your `AppBar` will not be scrollable. And you will get what you wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So my assumption is that the ViewPager gets the same height as the parent, but the AppBar takes up space at the top, so the ViewPager is shifted down.

You are absolutely correct.  This was a bit of a surprise to me too.

You have a couple options here.

- You can move the bottom-anchored view outside the view pager and anchor it to the bottom of the `CoordinatorLayout`.  This way it will always be visible no matter the scroll position of the content inside the view pager.

  When you do this, you do need to offset the view pager with a bottom margin so that when the content is scrolled up, it is entirely visible:

  ```
      <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
          android:id="@+id/container"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
          app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

      <TextView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="bottom"
          android:text="How low can you go."/>
  ```

  The downside to this is that the content doesn't move with the view pager.  I use this to method anchor buttons to the bottom that apply to the whole screen.
- If that content absolutely needs to be displayed all the time and paged as well, then perhaps the scrolling app bar isn't the right thing for your UI.  Change the `CoordinatorLayout` to a `LinearLayout` and use the `Toolbar` without the `AppBarLayout`.

Comment: This worked. (Same suggestion as himanshu. Thanks). Now the status bar (battery, antenna, messages etc.) is white. I'll go see if I can find a solution for that.

Comment: Found it: Don't change the `CoordinatorLayout` to `LinearLayout`, but add a `LinearLayout` inside the `CoordinatorLayout` (see [Stack overlow 32428700](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32428700/status-bar-turns-white-and-does-not-show-content-behind-it))