# ColorPrimaryDark Not comming as a Status bar color

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-appcompat, android-styles, android-statusbar

i have both style file in Application and it is not getting colorPrimaryDark as a Statusbar color. i am checking with Nexus 6 and it is not working in it.is something i am missing.

[image]

style.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>


    </style>


</resources>
```

style.xml(v21)

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <!--Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <!--All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>


</resources>
```

Menifest  - there is no theme define in any activity

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

color file

```
<color name="colorPrimary">#35734F</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#35734F</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#D2AB67</color>
```

Comment: post colors xml and manifest file

Comment: code is updated now.. @FerdousAhamed

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>` and `<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>` in your `style.xml(v21)`.

**style.xml**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">

</resources>
```

**style.xml(v21)**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <!--Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: And you may want to take a look at this link if some of your activities' status bar turn to white : https://stackoverflow.com/a/38182815/3121246

Answer (score 0):

change parent to "Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

</style>

</resources>
```