# Bottom bar falls to low behind the navigation bar

Tags: android, android-layout

Bottom navigation hide behind device buttons see below image :

[image]

I can't use any `scrollview` view or anything.

See below code of my activity:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    android:background="@color/offwhite"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_menu"
        />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_below="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/nav_Frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            >
        </FrameLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_home"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_myaccount"
                android:tint="@color/light_gray"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_notification"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_myaccount"
                android:tint="@color/light_gray"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_add"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_myaccount"
                android:tint="@color/light_gray"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_massage"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_myaccount"
                android:tint="@color/light_gray"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_account"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_myaccount"
                android:tint="@color/light_gray"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                />

        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

`style.xml` code:

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Is your app theme `FullScreen`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I search about this and finally i got it why this bottom navigation show under the bottom bar

i remove below Flag in my Java class.

`getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);`

I added this flag for mix up the `Actionbar` and `Statusbar`.

So I just remove this flag and it's look perfect. :)

Answer (score 1):

seperate your layout

content_layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_below="@+id/nav_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/nav_Frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    >
</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_home"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_myaccount"
        android:tint="@color/light_gray"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_notification"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_myaccount"
        android:tint="@color/light_gray"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_add"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_myaccount"
        android:tint="@color/light_gray"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_massage"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_myaccount"
        android:tint="@color/light_gray"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_account"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_myaccount"
        android:tint="@color/light_gray"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

drawer_activity.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:openDrawer="start"
android:background="#E2DEDE"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<include layout="@layout/content"/>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

add this in your app theme:

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">false</item>
```

Comment: i can't use any theme for this activity. and second one i'll create a custom `bottom navigationview` please check it

Comment: do you want to hide system navigatinview?

Comment: see my image i'll create a bottom `navigationview` using `linearlayout` but it's hide at device button

Answer (score 0):

extend your bottom navigation from

```
public class BottomNavigationBehavior extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<BottomNavigationView> {

public BottomNavigationBehavior() {
    super();
}

public BottomNavigationBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}
@Override
public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, BottomNavigationView child, View dependency) {
    boolean dependsOn = dependency instanceof FrameLayout;
    return dependsOn;
}
@Override
public boolean onStartNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, BottomNavigationView child, View directTargetChild, View target, int nestedScrollAxes) {
    return nestedScrollAxes == ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL;
}

@Override
public void onNestedPreScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, BottomNavigationView child, View target, int dx, int dy, int[] consumed) {
    if (dy < 0) {
        showBottomNavigationView(child);
    } else if (dy > 0) {
        hideBottomNavigationView(child);
    }
}

private void hideBottomNavigationView(BottomNavigationView view) {
    view.animate().translationY(view.getHeight());
}

private void showBottomNavigationView(BottomNavigationView view) {
    view.animate().translationY(0);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try This

add this in your activity xml:
root DrawerLayout:

```
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

To achieve this in any activity

1. Add the style:

> ```
> <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
>     <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
>     <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
>     <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
>     <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
>     <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
> </style>
> ```

2. Use CoordinatorLayout as root layout in XML for Activity
3. In `oncreate()` method, before setcontentview use

> window.decorView.systemUiVisibility =
>   View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or
>   View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN