# White statusbar when using Admob in activity layout

Tags: android, android-layout, admob

I am using CoordinatorLayout with RelativeLayout for displaying an Ad at the bottom. But what I am getting is white status bar. When I removed the relative layout and adview everything works fine. As I am wrapping CoordinatorLayout inside RelativeLayout what I get is a white status bar.

Using API v23 (marshmallow)

I also found related question here: [Status bar turns white and does not show content behind it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32428700/1820644)

The layout I used looks similar to the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31065486/1820644

But didn't helped me. I am still getting the white statusbar.

My **activity_layout.xml** file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.testapp.EventActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adView">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_plus_add" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_test_id" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After trying almost all the layouts, nesting layouts, the thing which finally worked was Putting a CoordinatorLayout as the root and putting another CoordinatorLayout inside it above adView.

The Layout hierarchy which I used is something like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
...  >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            ....
            android:layout_above="@+id/adView">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                ... />

        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            ... />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

So as CoordinatorLayout as the root it makes sure of the statusbar color.

What I was trying to achieve is done through **nesting of CoordinatorLayout** and **CoordinatorLayout as root element of activity layout**.

Full code of my layout file:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.testapp.EventActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/adView">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
                android:src="@drawable/btn_plus_add" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_bottom_event" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

It finally turned to be looks like this:

[image]

Comment: it works even with a single coordinator layout and with no relativelayout at all.