# Hide and show statusBar with Toolbar at the same time in android

Tags: android, statusbar, android-toolbar

I know this question asked many time and I tested solutions which provide but none of them works. I want to hide **StatusBar** and **Toolbar** so I use following code to hide **statusBar** base on [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation.html#40):

```
 int flags = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;

 getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(flags);
```

And this code for showing **statusBar**:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE);
```

It's works but When I hide **statusBar** my **darkPrimaryColor** is still visible like following pic (I use fade Animation with Translate for hiding **Toolbar**)

[image]

I also set fit `android:fitsSystemWindows="false"` But in this case **oolbar** goes behind **statusBar**.

I also see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33890066/white-statusbar-when-using-admob-in-activity-layout/33892569#33892569) but solution not work because I'm using **drawerLayout** as root.

Here is my layout:

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:id="@+id/root">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/appbar">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar" />

            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <include layout="@layout/view_epg_player" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout/>
```

Also try following code which green status-bar are disappear But it's not smooth and still looking for better approach, without causing a layout jerk.

**Hide status-bar**:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

**Show status-bar**

```
 getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: @snachmsm no, I want to handle this with AppCompat if be possible